# Getting current text of input field using Selenium

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, input, selenium-webdriver

Let's say I have this input element:

```
<input id="email" value="some@email.com">
```

I execute this piece of code:

```
var emailInputField = driver.FindElement(By.Id(email));
var email = emailInputField.GetAttribute("value");
emailInputField .InputField.Clear();
var empty = emailInputField.GetAttribute("value");
```

I would expect variable **empty** to be *empty* but it contains same text as **email** since I cleared the text. I realize that value attribute doesn't get synchronized with entered text, so my question is, how do I find out what text currently is in the text box?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you have already selected the element and assigned `emailInputField` to it then empty is going to refer to that. If you re-assign `emailInputField` after the clear and then get the value it should be empty. So :

```
var emailInputField = driver.FindElement(By.Id(email));
var email = emailInputField.GetAttribute("value");
emailInputField .InputField.Clear();
var empty = driver.FindElement(By.Id(email)).GetAttribute("value");
```

Comment: Excellent - thanks! 

Answer (score 0):

```
var emailInputField = driver.FindElement(By.Id(email));
var email = emailInputField.GetAttribute("value");
emailInputField.InputField.Clear();
var empty = emailInputField.GetAttribute("value");
```

In 3rd line your making mistake, try above one

Comment: Sorry, I made mistake while writing this example. I edited the original post.